# Can I completely remove the history of all files in selected subdirs of my repo?

Tags: git

I have a [testcase shell script](http://wuertele.com/sites/wuertele.com/files/test-prune).

I have a bloated repository, call it "oldrepo", that I'm trying to refactor.  The repository contains several directories of large files that I'm not interested in keeping.  I want them completely removed from history.  I know how to remove specific files [using filter-branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/how-do-i-remove-sensitive-files-from-gits-history), but I don't know how to remove everything EXCEPT for a specific directory or set of directories without going through and removing every file individually.

I thought I could fool git into doing this by creating a new repo and only merging the files that I want to keep:

```
mkdir newrepo
git init; touch README; git add .; git commit -m "initial"
git remote add oldrepo /path/to/oldrepo
git merge -s ours --no-commit
git read-tree --prefix=subdir1 -u
git commit -m "merged subdir1"
git remote rm oldrepo
git prune --verbose
```

Unfortunately, the prune command prunes nothing. I was hoping that it would prune every object that had never been a child of SUBDIR1-TREE. Is there a way to remove all history outside of a directory without individually removing each offending file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is also a job for `filter-branch`, but instead of removing select files/directories as mentioned in [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/how-do-i-remove-sensitive-files-from-gits-history) you can empty out the index completely using `git read-tree --empty` (for Git v1.7.4 or newer; if you're running an older version of Git use `git read-tree` with no arguments) and then restore the files/directories you want using `git reset`:

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git read-tree --empty && git reset -q "${GIT_COMMIT}" -- first_directory_to_keep second_directory_to_keep'
```

Comment: Thanks!  I've confirmed this works exactly as you say.  Then, to prune the objects, I run:

    `git remote rm origin;
    rm -Rf .git/refs/original;
    rm -Rf .git/logs/;
    git gc --prune=now`

I'm still trying to verify whether everything that should be gone is really gone.